# Bug in my Core php code - Regarding onclick and onload

Tags: javascript, php, dom-events

I have below code it works fine

```
<a href ="#" onclick="accept ("<?php echo $getservice [$i]['id']; ?>, document.frml)"> Accept </a>
```

In above code, I'm calling **Javascript** function by `onclick` event.

Now I want to change the event to `onload`, but it doesn't work.

```
<a href ="#" onload="accept ("<?php echo $getservice [$i]['id']; ?>, document.frml)"/>
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: can you please add some more codes

Comment: `<a>` tags don't support the `onload` attribute

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind the `onLoad` DOM event to the `<a>` element, so this is no bug and only related to the JS event handler, not PHP as your title suggest. If you want to fire an `onLoad` event you want to think of putting it into the `<body>`-tag instead.

See a reference here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events